Missing tests in ReportPortal when exporting from Gradle multi-module project
I have a Gradle multi-module project with JUnit 5 tests. To gather test results for many (but not all) modules at once in ReportPortal, the tests are executed by means of a Gradle task like this (Kotlin DSL):
tasks.register("selectedModulesTest") {
    finalizedBy(
        project(":fist-module").tasks.getByName("test"),
        project(":second-module").tasks.getByName("test"),
        project(":third-module").tasks.getByName("test")
    )
}

However, ReportPortal shows substantially less tests than were actually executed during the launch, for example, instead of 2520 it shows only 1705. No correspondence between certain modules and missing tests was observed. There are no errors neither in ReportPortal applications logs, nor in the client logs.
Trying to launch tests with test task on the root module yielded the same result, though the share of missed test changed a bit.
So the questions are:

Is there a special way for exporting test results to ReportPortal from Gradle multi-module project?
Is there a difference for ReportPortal on how the tests are executed: from the root test task or as a chain of separate test task invocations on individual modules?
How to find out which tests are missed and why?


Some details:

Report Portal 5.11.1 deployed with Docker Compose
Gradle 6.9, JDK 8

org.gradle.parallel=false


Report Portal dependencies in build.gradle.kts:

    testImplementation("com.epam.reportportal:agent-java-junit5:5.1.11")
    testImplementation("com.epam.reportportal:logger-java-log4j:5.1.4")


reportportal.properties contains only required entries (rp.endpoint, rp.api.key, rp.project, rp.launch), no customization was done.


I have no idea even what report portal is, so this is not a try to answer and thus just a comment. Just wanted to mention that project(":fist-module").tasks.getByName("test") is a very bad idea. It introduces project coupling by reaching into that other projects model and also just works if that project happens to have been configured already far enough for the task to be present. And even if it works, it disturbs more sophisticated Gradle features and optimizations. Better use dependsOn(":fist-module:test").

Thank you @Vampire for this note! I've inherited this code and now trying to make it work as expected. You comment helps me to do it properly.
